# android- how to set the text length in text view

Tags: textview, android

in my application i want to fit the text length means text view containing characters

Ex:
int x is fit with 3 means it accepts up to 3 characters only.
suppose 
x=9999 it is not accepted
x=99 it is accepted

How to set this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

android:width="3" use this in your XML

Answer (score 0):

```java
TextView editEntryVew = new TextView(...);
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editEntryView.setFilters(FilterArray);
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for the OP